# Angular application not detected, message is getting shown in angular dev tool

Tags: angular, iframe, extjs

Angular application not detected, message is getting shown in angular dev tool.

I have an angular application which is present in Ext JS iframe.

Now in order to utilize the angular Dev tool, I am not seeing any thing apart from message like 'Angular application not detected'.

[image]

Note- Getting proper information in angular dev tool if try to access the angular application directly outside the **iframe** via hitting the url

Could anyone help me out here, thanks.

Comment: Anyone got any solution to why it is not able to detect any workaround? Please share